# Coredata with multiple context and nested perfromblockandwait implementation confusion

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, deadlock, nsoperation

am having a app which syncs data from cloud, this happens on NSOperationqueue. The app has one main MOC that has mainqueue concurrency and an NSOperation subclass that has child MOC with private queue concurrency. whenever the user press the sync button that NSoperation to sync data is started. The process is as below:

```
local.performBlockAndWait 
{
//1. upload local to cloud and resolve conflicts . 

if !local.hasChanges { return }
 do {
    try local.save()
    parent.performBlockAndWait {
        do {
            try parent.save()
        } catch {
            print("wasSuccessful error1 \(error)")
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed to save local: \(error)")
}



//2. download cloud to local and save changes to local 

if !local.hasChanges { return }
 do {
    try local.save()
    parent.performBlockAndWait {
        do {
            try parent.save()
        } catch {
            print("wasSuccessful error1 \(error)")
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("Failed to save local: \(error)")
}
```

}

note: The above process happens inside the nsoperation subclass, which is scheduled inside a NSOperation queue. So by no change it will be on mainqueue.

Will this code cause deadlock? Googled everyone suppose to have mix opinion and sentences like never to use performblockandwait on mainMOC etc. So do i need to change above code?

EDIT :
The local store is created as below:

```
@objc public class CKSIncrementalStoreSyncOperation: NSOperation
{

override public func main() 
{
    self.localStoreMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    self.localStoreMOC?.parentContext = OSCDStackManager.sharedManager().managedObjectContext;

 self.localStoreMOC?.performBlockAndWait(
 { () -> Void in

        autoreleasepool 
        {
            if self.syncCompletionBlock != nil
            {
                self.funSyncStart({ (isSycned, error) -> () in

                        self.syncCompletionBlock!(syncError: error)
                 })                
            }

        }
})

  }
//Sync Code 
}
```

Edit :

1. SyncompletionBlock : It just notifies the completion of the sync operation and make other UIupdates. It is as below.

   ```
   self.syncOperation?.syncCompletionBlock =  ({(error) -> Void in

       self.isSyncing = false

       if error == nil
       {
           NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in

               AlertControllerAlloction.funReturnAlert("Synced successfully.", subTitleP: "Synced successfully.", closeButtonTitleP: "Ok", durationP: 0.0, type: 5, array: nil, delegate: nil)

               let myDict : NSDictionary = ["isSuccess":true];

               NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(secureCloudCompletionNotification, object: nil, userInfo: myDict as [NSObject : AnyObject])
           })

       }
       else
       {
           NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in

               AlertControllerAlloction.funReturnAlert("Server Busy", subTitleP: "An error occurred during the synchronization process. Please try again after a few minutes.", closeButtonTitleP: "Ok", durationP: 0.0, type: 2, array: nil, delegate: nil) // text change 10/11

               let myDict : NSDictionary = ["isSuccess":false,"SyncError":error!]

               NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(secureCloudCompletionNotification, object: nil, userInfo: myDict as [NSObject : AnyObject])
           })
       }
   })
   ```

   2. The funStartSync Method calls another method which in turn calls another method and so on. The local context is used throughout the NSOperation class to fetch changes made in local db to upload to cloud, if conflicts happen the resolve the by comparing last modified date, and once changes are fetched from cloud in part 2, apply those in local db. So the managed object are spread throughout the class.

Should i remove `performBlockAndWait()` from here and put it at all the places i access local db and managed objects?

Comment: Show how local is defined and created

Comment: Have edit the question to include the local store creation

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question you asked previously.

Your `main()` method as a lot of extra work in it that it probably does not need.

```
@objc public class CKSIncrementalStoreSyncOperation: NSOperation {

  override public func main() {
    self.localStoreMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    self.localStoreMOC?.parentContext = OSCDStackManager.sharedManager().managedObjectContext;

    self.localStoreMOC?.performBlockAndWait {
      if self.syncCompletionBlock != nil {
        self.funSyncStart({ (isSycned, error) in
          self.syncCompletionBlock!(syncError: error)
        })                
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the point of calling `syncCompletionBlock` inside of the queue for the private MOC?  Is that where your other code block exists?  If so then that is most likely your problem as you are tripping up the `performBlockAndWait` by calling it twice from two difference functions and thereby confusing the context.  I said before that calling PB&W was safe, and it is.  But you can still trip it up if you try hard enough :)

Please show `funSyncStart` and `syncCompletionBlock` so that I can follow your code and help you clean this up.

> Actually i missed your edit on last question :) .The issues pointed out by concurrency debug variable are cleared out now. Also used GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging.h it showed that objects were released on another thread and solved it by adding autoreleasepool. Actually had a doubt that even if everything is working fine now, if i have missed something it just get pointed out before the data loss for user happen. Thanks for your help marcus have edit the question to add syncCompletionBlock, the funstartsync us just calling another method and so on.

First, I would not trust a third part library for concurrency testing on Core Data.  The `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` is the only canonical test for concurrency.  What that pod is doing is highly suspect.

Second, you do not need the autorelease pool; at all.  There are situations, especially when you are working with queues like this where objects will get released later, much later, by the system.  The code you presented is not leaking memory.

Third, Your question ask **if** something will deadlock which implies that you are not testing this code.  Is it deadlocking?  Have you run the code?

If it actually is (rather than theatrical question of will it) locking, then when it locks, go into the debugger, pause the application and **see** where it is deadlocking.

Having said all of that.  Assuming that your first code block in the question is the internals of `funSyncStart` then you are calling `performBlockAndWait` twice in a row on the same context.  While that *should not* cause a deadlock, it is wasteful and poor code.  If you are calling `performBlockAndWait` in the main method then there is no reason to call it ever again in any of the sub methods that you are calling from the main!  You are already on the right queue there is no reason to jump onto the right queue again.

`performBlockAndWait` jumps to the correct queue, executes the closure and blocks the calling queue.  If you keep calling it, it should be a no-op but ideally you should only call it once to keep your code clean.

Comment: Actually i missed your edit on last question :) .The issues pointed out by concurrency debug variable are cleared out now. Also used GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging.h it showed that objects were released on another thread and solved it by adding autoreleasepool. Actually had a doubt that even if everything is working fine now, if i have missed something it just get pointed out before the data loss for user happen. Thanks for your help marcus have edit the question to add syncCompletionBlock, the funstartsync us just calling another method and so on.

Comment: Answer updated.  Please confirm that the first code block in your question is `funSyncStart` since you did not show the func.

Comment: Okay thanks marcus. yes have tested the code it's not deadlocking any number of runs. Yes am calling performblockandwait only in the main method and not in any of the method or blocks after. The first block was just an simplified example of what am doing through the NSoperationclass, :)  the funstartsync method does not have any calls of performblockandwait on the local context after.

Comment: Excellent, then you should be golden.  It is pretty hard to deadlock the PB&W calls even when you try :)